# Windows not showing full DEll MD3000i volume size

Tags: dell-powervault

I have a DEll MD3000i that connects directly to a Dell R610 server (with Windows 2008 standard OS) via the iSCSI connections.  The MD3000i shows 5TB in the Disk Management Console, but windows only shows it as 4TB.  Any idea of how to get windows to show the full 5TB?

Answer (score 1):

How's it partitioned? it should be using GPT not MBR for that size.